# Calculate annual profit from running the server

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I have an upcoming interview and below question was asked in the interview from another candidate.

- Our sever run cost is `$300` and other fixed costs are `$200`
- The server can accommodate `30TB` of traffic.
- We have about `50 customers`, and each customer pays us a server usage fee of `$30/month.`
- We allocate `100GB` to each user, but on average each user will only use `60% of the swap.`
- So we can use the remaining space to accommodate more customers.

**Q: What is the annual profit?**

`My Approach:`

- `30TB = 30,000GB`
- If we allocate `100GB` to every customer then the server can accommodate `300 customers.`
- We only have `50 customers`, so, we can add `250 more customers.`
- Total of `300 customers` will bring revenue of `$9000.`
- Out of `30,000GB`, `60%` will be used on an average.
- Remaining `40% provides us 12,000GB`
- `12,000GB` can be allocated to `120 more customers.`
- `120 customers` will bring revenue of `$6000.`
- Total revenue = 9000+6000 = `$15000`
- Total operating cost = `300+200` = `$500`
- Total profit = `$15000 - $500` = `$14,500`

**Please let me know if the above approach looks correct.**

Comment: If maximum number of customers that can be accommodated is 300 and per customer revenue is $\$30$/mo, isn't revenue capped at $300 \times \$30 = \$9000$/mo? How can profit be greater than revenue?

Comment: This is total revenue from 300 customer. But, we can accommodate 120 more customers, right?

Comment: You said: "If we allocate 100GB to every customer then the server can accommodate 300 customers."

Which server will you accomodate the 301st customer?

Comment: Did you mean to say the server can accommodate more than 300 customers, but 300 *concurrent* customers?

Comment: 300 customers will be given all the memory. However, 300 customer only use 60% memory. so remaining 40% can be allocated to more customers. This is my understanding.

Comment: I totally agree with that and with your `Approach`. An interview question should not require the level of sophistication that led @wg to a more complicated approach.

Answer (score 1):

This problem does not makes sense the way it is specified.

If this is treated like a time-sharing system with a maximum of 300 concurrent customers and the 301-st customer just waits for a slot to open (when one of the active customer logs out and doesn't care about how much wait time they endure), then there is no limit to the maximum number of customers you can sign up because the customers #301 onwards will have unbounded wait times. That means revenue is unbounded (and therefore profit is unbounded).

If customers expect to be able to login without waiting and they don't care about how many other customers are concurrently logged in, the system is bounded by 300 customers max, even if the memory (or bandwidth) utilization is only 60%. Therefore, revenue is bounded by $\$9000$/mo and hence profit.

If we are thinking let us extract some more juice from the 40% underutilization (of memory or bandwidth), then the parameters around what is *acceptable* service level has to be defined. We would then have to model utilization patterns of the customers to determine an optimal number of customers.